# Why no functions in a class' private array

Tags: php

I've tried to access a function in a class private array, but i've got an error:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' in CODE on line 17 Errors parsing CODE**

this is my code:

```
<?php

function foo_function () {

    return 'foo_value';
}

class foo {

    private $good_foo_var = array (

        'foo_key' => 'anything'
    );

    private $bad_foo_var = array (

        'foo_key' => foo_function ()
    );

    public function get_the_foo () {

        return $this -> foo_var['foo_key'];

    }

}
```

I have no idea why. Outside a class this kind of assignment is no problem.

Comment: This has to do with the fact that properties which are defined in the class definition are instantiated in compile-time. Functions are not available during compile-time and instantiation of such a property thus needs to be done during run-time. This is why you should not provide such values in the definition, but rather in the constructor.

Comment: Your foo_function() is out of scope in the class file ..

Comment: Scope is not an issue; in PHP all functions are in the global scope, regardless of where they are defined (unless defined in a namespace)

Comment: @Tularis this is true in above example for `foo_function()`, but not for `get_the_foo()`, which is not in global scope.

Comment: True, it's not, but it's a method, not just a function. I was aiming at the use (and mislocation) of foo_function as explained by Abhik. But yes, methods are indeed scoped to just that class/object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties which are defined in your class are instantiated during compile-time. This means that the value is not evaluated, but has to be a constant value. Function returns are not constant values, so have to be evaluated during run-time. For this you should instantiate them in your constructor.

See for more information the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Answer (score 3):

That is because currently *you can not* have anything in your properties default values, but things that are not runtime-evaluated. That means - if some thing will be evaluated at runtime, it can not be used in property default value.

To overcome that, use class constructor:

```
class foo 
{

    private $good_foo_var = array (

        'foo_key' => 'anything'
    ); 

    public function get_the_foo () 
    {

        return $this -> foo_var['foo_key'];

    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bad_foo_var = array (
           'foo_key' => foo_function ()
        );
    }

}
```

However, since PHP 5.6 will be released, [constant expressions](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/const_scalar_exprs) will be available for using in such cases. They won't allow you to use *just anything* there, but definitely will allow more wide default value definition.

To understand this restriction you'll need to understand that syntax for properties has intention to define **default** property value which can not be something dynamic. I.e. sense of "default" itself assumes that value must be known at startup context.

Comment: more, yes; but still not functions like this.

Comment: @Tularis yes, because that goes against definition of what is _default value_